# The command/opt/shift key assigned to the side button of the mouse does not respond only within blender

Tags: customization

I am using blender v3.3.4 for MacOS.
I have set up three different keys, command/opt/shift, on the side button of the mouse, but none of them respond within blender and I am having trouble.

When I assign the tab or A-Z keys, they respond when pressed, but only when I assign command/opt/shift, they do not respond.

For example, if I assign command+s to a mouse button, the shortcut for pressing only the s key, scale, works instead of the save function, which is a shortcut already set for command+s.

When input is made from the keyboard, all keys in command/opt/shift work correctly.

Is there a place in blender to configure settings related to mouse key assignments?

The PC used is a 2019 iMac (Intel) and the current OS version is sonoma14.3.